# Multiplication and addition of two multilevel data-frame based on index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two data frames df1 and df2. Both data-frames have same index UNKNOWN, step1,step2,step3.

**df1:**

```
FE             F1        F2
C_Step                     
UNKNOWN  0.336134  0.165289
step1    0.126050  0.371901
step2    0.201681  0.297521
step3    0.336134  0.165289
```

**df2:**

```
DT             D1                    D2               
RE             E1     E2        E3   E1   E2        E3
C_Step                                                
UNKNOWN  0.571429  0.000  0.219780  0.0  0.5  0.000000
step1    0.428571  0.000  0.164835  1.0  0.0  0.555556
step2    0.000000  0.375  0.395604  0.0  0.0  0.444444
step3    0.000000  0.625  0.219780  0.0  0.5  0.000000
```

I want to do multiplication and addition operation on **EACH** column of df1 with df2. The structure of resulting data-frame (df3) is shown below (each of column of dataframe df1 with each column of df2).

1) All **UNKNOWN** index should be filled with zero.

2) Other indexes: (df1 * UNKNOWN index of df2) + (df2 * UNKNOWN index of df1)

For example: In first column,
Value of 'UNKNOWN': 0.00000

Value of 'step1' index: (0.126050 * 0.571429) + (0.428571 * 0.336134) = 0.21609

Value of 'step2':
(0.201681 * 0.571429) + (0.00000 * 0.336134) = 0.11525

Value for step 3:
(0.336134 * 0.571429) + (0.0000 * 0.336134) = 0.19208

so on for all the other multilevel columns

**df3:** Example

```
DT             D1                                 D2                      \
RE             E1        E2        E3             E1        E2        E3   
FE             F1   F2   F1   F2   F1        F2   F1   F2   F1   F2   F1   
C_Step                                                                     
UNKNOWN    0.00000  0    0    0    0         0    0    0.....
step1      0.21609 ...
step2      0.11525
step3      0.19208

DT                 
RE                 
FE             F2  
C_Step             
UNKNOWN        0
step1     
step2     
step3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose d1 is first data frame and d2 is second data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul
from itertools import product
#second multiplication
m1 = d1.copy()   #unknown values
s = m1.iloc[0].values
for i in range(0,4):
    m1.iloc[i] = s
m1.iloc[0] = 0    

#print(m1)    
m2 = d2.copy()  #unknown values
s = m2.iloc[0].values
for i in range(0,4):
    m2.iloc[i] = s
m2.iloc[0] = 0

#print(m2)    

second1 = pd.concat({k: reduce(mul, (d[c] for d, c in zip([d1, m2], k)))for k in product(d1, d2)}, axis=1)   
second2 = pd.concat({k: reduce(mul, (d[c] for d, c in zip([m1, d2], k)))for k in product(d1, d2)}, axis=1)   

#add dataframes together
summation = sum([second1, second2])
```